# Mocha / jsdom "SecurityError: localStorage is not available for opaque origins"

Tags: vue.js, webpack, mocha.js, local-storage, jsdom

I get this error when testing with Mocha and jsdom my Vue components and using localStorage in them:

```
[Vue warn]: Error in data(): "SecurityError: localStorage is not available for opaque origins"
```

All the issues I could find on Github or here do reference to Jest and the solutions suggest to set the Jest config option testUrl to any valid URL. But how to set it directly on the jsdom instance?

When I add an options object when initialising jsdom - nothing happens:

```
let jsdom = require('jsdom-global')(
    {
        url: "https://dev.wue-theme.test"
    }
);
```

Comment: [Related Github discussion](https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom/issues/2383)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, looking into jsdom's index.js helped - the first parameter is expecting an HTML string or undefined to set a default HTML string/wrapper, the options object goes as the second parameter:

```
let jsdom = require('jsdom-global')(
    undefined,
    {
        url: "https://dev.wue-theme.test"
    }
);
```

Now when running mocha test the error has gone indeed