# origin issue that doesnt allow me to use localStorage with JSDOM

Tags: javascript, node.js, jsdom

So I'm trying to load a webpage in a node environment with JSDOM. The webpage makes use of localStorage.

I'm loading the webpage through file system using JSDOM's url config option. JSDOM gives me the following error:

```
Error: Uncaught [SecurityError: localStorage is not available for opaque origins]
```

It gives this error if document.origin is set to null. I have no clue how to set origin using this setup. Can anyone help me out?

I have prepared a sandbox with the exact error [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/nice-haibt-2lehn?file=/src/index.js)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's meaningless to use `localStorage` within a NodeJS (i.e. server-side) environment because there's no web-browser context - or am I missing something?

Comment: yes, it is for testing. JSDOM simulates the browser.

Comment: Have you seen this? https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom/issues/2304

Comment: Yes, I'm not using jest.

Answer (score 0):

Old, but for reference, I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57318088/128595), so just doing something like

```
new JSDOM("...", { url: "https://localhost/" })
```

works.